# $.ajax call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

In IE9 following code showing JScript does not support $.ajax() method and in FF it's not showing any arror but the task it is supposed to do is not being done.I am attaching my aspx code and code behind method also.I have included all the necessary libraries in the code-behind.

```
<table class="style3">
    <tr>
        <td><label id="lname" >Name</td>
        <td><input id="name" type="text" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label id="ldept">Department</label></td>
        <td><select id="dept">
        <option value="TnH">Travel & Hospitality</option>
        <option value="BFS">Banking & Financial Services</option>
        <option value="Insurance">Insurance</option>
        <option value="Communication">Communication</option>
        <option value="HealthCare">HealthCare</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label id="lcontact">Contact</label></td>
        <td><input id="contact" type="text" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label id="lage">Age</label></td>
        <td><input id="age" type="text" runat="server"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="hdnBtn" runat="server" onclick="AddEmployee" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hname" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdept" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hcontact" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hage" runat="server" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">



 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#dialog-form").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        var hdnBtn=document.getElementById("<%=hdnBtn.ClientID %>");
        $("#hdnBtn").hide();
        $("#diaglog-form").hide();   
        $("#addBtn").click(function()
        {
        $("#diaglog-form").show();   
            $("#diaglog-form").dialog(
            {
                open:function()
                {
                    $("#this").parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
                },
                title: 'Add New Employee',
                modal:true,
                minHeight:300,
                minWidth:440,

                buttons:
                {
                    Add:function()
                    {   

//                        $("#hname").val($("#name").val());
//                        $("#hdept").val($("#dept").val());
//                        $("#hcontact").val($("#contact").val());
//                        $("#hage").val($("#age").val());
//                        $("#hdnBtn").click();
                        var name=name.val();
                        var dept=dept.val();
                        var contact=contact.val();
                        var age=age.val();
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
  //                      data: "{name: '" + name.val() + "',dept:"+dept.val()+"',contact:"+contact.val()+"',age:"+age.val()+"'}",
                        data: {name:name,dept:dept,contact:contact,age:age},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        processData:false,
                        success : function(data) 
                        { 
                        // in case you would use a return value in your webmethod
                        $("#btnAllEmp").click();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                        });


                    },
                   close:function()
                   {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
                }
            }
            );
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Libraries I attached :-

```
<script src="JQuery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
     <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JQuery/jquery.ui.effect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link href="Stylesheets/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Stylesheets/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
     <link href="Stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The code-behind method:-

```
[WebMethod]
        public static void GetData(string jsonData)
        {
            //string name = collection["name"] as string;
            //string dept = collection["dept"] as string; ;
            //string contact = collection["contact"] as string; ;
            //string age = collection["age"] as string; ;

            EmployeeEntity emp = new EmployeeEntity();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            emp = serializer.Deserialize<EmployeeEntity>(jsonData);

            string name = emp.EmpName;
            string dept = emp.EmpDept;
            string contact = emp.EmpContact;
            string age = emp.EmpAge;
            string text = name + " " + dept + " " + contact + " " + age + " ";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\WriteText.txt", text);

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
            String cmdText = "INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES('" + name + "','" + dept + "','" + contact + "','" + age + "')";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
```

[EDIT]

```
var name=$("#name").val();
                        var dept=$("#dept").val();
                        var contact=$("#contact").val();
                        var age=$("#age").val();
                        var data=JSON.stringify({name:name,dept:dept,contact:contact,age:age});
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetData",
  //                      data: "{name: '" + name.val() + "',dept:"+dept.val()+"',contact:"+contact.val()+"',age:"+age.val()+"'}",
                        data: data,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        async: true,
                        processData:false,
                        success : function(data) 
                        { 
                        // in case you would use a return value in your webmethod
                        $("#btnAllEmp").click();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                        });
```

and after using JQuery 1.10.2 the $.ajax() is getting recognised.Thanks
But the GetData() is not doing anything,Data is not getting inserted in the database.Please Help

[EDIT 1]

```
error:function(resp,textStatus,errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert("Error : "+errorThrown);
                        }
                        });
```

its giving "Error:Internal Server Error".Please help me now

Comment: Why do you have two jquery.js files i.e. `9.0` and `9.1`?

Comment: nice SQL injection attack vector you have there...

Comment: @user2771527 I think `Script` and `style` path is not found in your page that might be problem.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your parameters like this

```
JSON.stringify({name:name,dept:dept,contact:contact,age:age}),
```

and where the value is coming in these

```
 var name=name.val();
 var dept=dept.val();
 var contact=contact.val();
 var age=age.val();
```

Comment: In IE why $.ajax() is showing "$ does not support this method"?

Comment: there should be some problem in your jquery. you are using 1.9.0 and 1.9.1. firstly check that if var debt = $("#ldept"); debt is getting some value here.

Comment: var name=name.val();
                        var dept=dept.val();
                        var contact=contact.val();
                        var age=age.val();
                        var data=JSON.stringify({name:name,dept:dept,contact:contact,age:age});

Answer (score 0):

It's because the parameters of the ajax call don't match those of the web method. On the client you this:

```
...data: {name:name,dept:dept,contact:contact,age:age},..
```

and in your web method you have this:

```
public static void GetData(string jsonData)
```

The solution, if there aren't any other issues, is to make them match; on the server, you can change the method's signature to this:

```
public static void GetData(string name, string dept, string contact, string age)
```

That way, you can remove all the deserialization that you're doing server-side and have your parameters directly accessible.

Note that your web method, as it's written, seems vulnerable to SQL injections! You're passing parameters to write SQL on the fly that's immediately executed on the database.

Comment: I tried public static void GetData(string name, string dept, string contact, string age) this way of accessing variables..But its not working

Comment: Well then there's another problem somewhere else but for sure non-matching parameters are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing the JSON is in the format of

```
 var jsonData =   [{"name":"kiteplayer","dept":"XXX"}{" name":"user","dept":"YYY"}]
```

Also try using the

```
 data : JSON.stringify(jsonData )
```

Also try to add the JSON-2.js for IE support. I used this.Hope this helps.